# How to create sqlite database within bundle during iPhone runtime?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I've tried using sqlite3_open statement, but the database is created at root level of my hard disk.

I can actually try to copy it to the bundle document folder. But,

1. Where will the database created if I execute it during the iPhone runtime? (Since I use iOS Simulator, it is created on root level).
2. How to create the database at the documents folder level immediately?

I'm sorry if I can't make myself clear enough, I'm really new working with database and stuffs.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not write to the main bundle, because it is signed with SSL certificate. But you can write to the document directory. Have a look at this link of how to create database at runtime in documents directory - [create sqlite db programmatically in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599453/create-sqlite-db-programmatically-in-iphone-sdk/3599505#3599505)

Comment: I have found out how to do that, there is an API to access user directory. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You should create database file template with no content, but with structure, that you plan to use in your app. Add this template to your project `Resources` folder. Then, when app started, copy that file to `Documents` folder and use it.